# Finding the second positive value in an array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to create a program that outputs the second positive value in an array of integers. If there is no second positive number, it will output "not positive enough." However, my function doesn't work for some reason. Would someone be able to point out why? Thanks :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NOT_POSITIVE_ENOUGH 0

int array_second_positive(int size, int array[size]) {
    int second_array[size];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i < size) {
        if (array[i] > 0) {
            scanf("%d", &second_array[j]);
            j++;
        }
    i++;
    }

    if (j < 2) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return second_array[1];
    }
}

#define MAX_SIZE 100

int main(void) {
    int size1 = 7;
    int array1[MAX_SIZE] = {3, -14, 15, 9, 2, 6, 5};

    int result1 = array_second_positive(size1, array1);
    if (result1 == NOT_POSITIVE_ENOUGH) {
        printf("array1 wasn't positive enough!\n");
    } else {
        printf("The second positive value from array1 is: %d\n", result1);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you give the wrong testcase ?

Comment: In your array_second_positive function, when you find a positive number then you should put that in the second_array array. Although you can simplify your code too. You don't need the second_array.

Comment: What did you do when you found the program did not work? Did you debug it by running in a debugger and/or add more debug print statements?

Comment: There isn't a wrong testcase. I'm pretty new to coding. Would you be able to show how I can simplify my function? I thought I was putting each positive number into the second_array array by iterating j.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was simple , please change :-

```
scanf("%d", &second_array[j]);
```

To :

```
second_array[j] = array[i];
```

Be careful when you code !

Comment: Thank you :) I tried to upvote your answer, but it doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: @comp_questions You could accept the answer by clicking tick symbol. To upvote you need points more than 15.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `scanf("%d", &second_array[j]);` probably does not do what you think it does. Refer to (for example): [scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf), and consider using:
`second_array[j] = array[i];` instead.

Though a simpler and more concise approach would be:

```
int array_second_positive(int size, int *arr) {
    int found = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > 0) {
            if (found) return arr[i];
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```